# Assigning Initial values for a certain parameter in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I have a certain parameter say 'X(m)' which is defined over the set 'M' such as 'M ./.M1*M10/'  How can I assign an initial value for that parameter 'X0' without conflicting with it's defined over the set 'M' which starts from '1-10', Any suggestions will be deeply valuable ? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to assign to X(M0), you're out of luck as M0 is not an element.

You may wish to disable domain checking for X by declaring it as X(*) and referencing X(m) and X("0").